# Append an element in a XML using DOM keeping the format

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

i have a xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Empleado>
  <ConsultorTecnico>
    <Nombre>Pablo</Nombre>
    <Legajo antiguedad="4 meses">7778</Legajo>
  </ConsultorTecnico>
  <CNC>
    <Nombre>Brian</Nombre>
    <Legajo antiguedad="1 año, 7 meses">2134</Legajo>
  <Sueldo>4268.0</Sueldo>
  </CNC>
</Empleado>
```

What i want is to read a XML and append "Sueldo" at the same level than "Nombre" and "Legajo" in the element "CNC". "Sueldo" must be "Legajo" x 2

The code I have appends "Sueldo" as you can see in the XML above but it does not indent it as it should, Im using the propierties to indent (This XML is created the same way, using DOM)

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
          File xml = new File("C:\\Empleado.xml");
          if (xml.exists() == true)
          {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(xml);

            String legajo = doc.getElementsByTagName("Legajo").item(1).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

        Element sueldo = doc.createElement("Sueldo");
        Node valorSueldo = doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(Float.valueOf(legajo)*2));
        sueldo.appendChild(valorSueldo);

        Node cnc = doc.getElementsByTagName("CNC").item(0);

        cnc.appendChild(sueldo);

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();

        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        t.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount","2"); 

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Empleado.xml");
        StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(fos);

        t.transform(source,sr);    

        }
      else
          throw new Exception("No hay archivo XML con ese nombre en el directorio");
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Thank you in advance guys, I'll appreciate the help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input file is the same as the output you've shown but without the `Sueldo` element, then the initial `CNC` element has *five* child nodes as far as the DOM is concerned

- The whitespace text node (newline and four spaces) between `<CNC>` and `<Nombre>`
- The `Nombre` element node
- The whitespace text node (newline and four spaces) between `</Nombre>` and `<Legajo`
- The `Legajo` element node
- The whitespace text node (newline and *two* spaces) between `</Legajo>` and `</CNC>`

You are inserting the `Sueldo` element after this final text node, which produces

```
  <CNC>
    <Nombre>Brian</Nombre>
    <Legajo antiguedad="1 año, 7 meses">2134</Legajo>
  <Sueldo>4268.0</Sueldo></CNC>
```

and the `INDENT` output property simply moves the closing `</CNC>` tag to the next line, aligned with the opening one.  To get the auto indentation to do the right thing you would need to remove *all* the whitespace-only text nodes from the initial tree.

Alternatively, forget the auto-indentation and do it yourself - instead of adding `Sueldo` as the *last* child of `CNC` (after that final text node), instead add a newline-and-four-spaces text node immediately after the `Legajo` (i.e. before the last text node) and then add the `Sueldo` element after that.

---

As an alternative approach entirely, I would consider doing the transformation in XSLT rather than using the DOM APIs

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <!-- ignore whitespace-only text nodes in the input -->
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <!-- and re-indent the output -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <!-- Copy everything verbatim except where otherwise specified -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- For CNC elements, add a Sueldo as the last child -->
  <xsl:template match="CNC">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      <Sueldo><xsl:value-of select="Legajo * 2" /></Sueldo>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which you could either run using the `TransformerFactory` API from Java code or using a standalone command-line XSLT processor.

Comment: So, i added the whitespaces as an element since it was the easier thing to do (I think it was not the best though) and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

XML does not intrinsically define any indentation or pretty-form.  If you want it to be "indented", you need to insert content with newlines and spaces.  In this case, you need content immediately after element `Legajo` and before element `Sueldo`.

To my taste, the best strategy is to **ignore** all formatting from XML files and use generalized prettyfiers immediately before human consumption.  Or, better, give them good XML editors.  If you have every program that manipulates XML files concerned about this detail, most of the benefits of XML are gone (and a lot of effort misused).

**UPDATE**:  Just noticed that you are using element `CNC` to "position" the insert, not `Legajo`.  The space-and-newlines content needs to go immediately before element `CNC` (and after element `Sueldo`).